# Likelihood ratio as minimal sufficient statistics in infinite parameter space

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, likelihood, likelihood-ratio, sufficient-statistics

I just read a question from here ([Likelihood ratio minimal sufficient](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/304450/likelihood-ratio-minimal-sufficient)) and have some thoughts. Let me restate the question first:

Consider a family of density functions $f(x|\theta)$ where the parameter space for $\theta$ is finite, that is, $\theta \in \{\theta_0, \cdots, \theta_p\}$. Assume that $\theta_0$ is such that $f(x|\theta_0) > 0$ for all $x$ on the support. Now consider the statistic $T(\mathbf{X})  = \left(\frac{f(\mathbf{X}|\theta_1)}{f(\mathbf{X}|\theta_0)}, \cdots, \frac{f(\mathbf{X}|\theta_p)}{f(\mathbf{X}|\theta_0)} \right)$.

I can show that this is the minimum sufficient statistics easily. However, I just wonder why we need the parameter space to be finite? Can we extend this result to infinite case? Why or why not?

Comment: *Obviously* not, because there aren't any examples where the minimal sufficient statistic has infinitely many components!  The very simplest textbook examples concern a one-dimensional parameter space, which implies the number of possible values of $\theta$ is *uncountably* infinite.

Comment: @whuber I am confused by your second sentence, why one-dimensional vector space implies  the number of possible values of 
 is uncountably infinite? And can you be more rigorous on why the minimal sufficient statistic should not have infinitely many components? Thank you

Comment: Please [search our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=minimal+sufficient+statistic) for examples.